# Mysql data storage

Tags: mysql, storage, user-information-list

I recently started a new project but I have a question about storing user information. In my app, the user can choose a type of beer and rate it. I want to store a list of beer for every user.

I am not sure how to do this.

Is it better to make a table for every user or is it better to make one big list with a reference to a user in every row?

I would be very thankfull if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

normaly you should do it with 3 tables: user, beers, user_beers

```
Users: userid | email | password ..
Beers: beerid | brand | name ..  
User_Beers: userbeerid | userid | beerid | stars
```

Never make tables for each users or products..